Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type '' Error
this is my webApi project program.cs file
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using testApi.Data;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlite(connectionString));

var app = builder.Build();






// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
    
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

i take this error when i want use migrations :
Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[testApi.Data.ApplicationDbContext]'
while attempting to activate 'testApi.Data.ApplicationDbContext'.'
please help me to solve that
thanks

Looks like your  ApplicationDbContext is not well defined. Can you share the content of ApplicationDbContext ?


Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'Unable to
resolve service for type
'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[testApi.Data.ApplicationDbContext]'
while attempting to activate 'testApi.Data.ApplicationDbContext'.'

According to your error message it seems, you haven't injected your DbContext Service as your service scope. If your ApplicationDbContext created as service in other class project that needed to be added as AddScoped
So you should include as following:
builder.Services.AddScoped<DbContext, ApplicationDbContext>();

Apart from that, while executing migration command, please make sure you have selected right class project from the dropdown below. In your scenario, you should choose the class project where your ApplicationDbContext residing into which is testApi.Data.ApplicationDbContext

In addition, please check your DbContex and appsettings.json file if those are configured accordingly.
You should have following:
public class ApplicationDbContext: DbContext
{

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }//Should be your DbSet
    public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TaskModel> Tasks { get; set; }


}

Connnection string  in appsettings.json:
Your connection string should be as following:
"ConnectionStrings": {
   "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=YourDatabaseName;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
 },

Last but not the least, make sure you have installed, required nuget package for your application in order to execute entityframework command and migration command. You should have following packages:

Note: Double check, if you have attached your DbContext class library proejct within the main project accordingly. In addition, please refer to this official document.
